# Localization don't show on device

Tags: java, android, kotlin, localization

I have added string localisation according to the instructions found on [Android Official Documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization). But despite that when I run the app with the langauge & input set prioritising one of then non default languages that have been translated, it doesn't appear in that language on the app.

I have tried 2 physical devices and a virtual one.

I have added the correct files:
[image]

I have set my device through language and input to one of the translated languages:
[image]

All other apps such as google maps then appear in the new language, but, my app still appears in English (my default language).

Every string that is in the default is translated in the other languages.

I am using Android Studio 3.5 Beta 5.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try force stoping the app --> launch again and confirm the result.

Comment: Hi Giddy, Just tried that there but it didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you using the debug version or the app bundle?
Because app bundles split the apk and load only the necessary resources.

Comment: Doesn't matter what version I use it is still in English. That includes release configured in Android Studio and a release version on the app store.

Comment: Can you make sure you have the default strings.xml file inside the values folder?

Comment: Yes, Inside the res folder there is a values folder and inside of that I have a strings.xml

Comment: Is it possible to send a sample source code ? If yes, send it to theapache64@gmail.com. I'll take a look into it.

Comment: Sorry, that's not possible.

Comment: Any `resConfig` in your app's build.gradle that would remove those other translations?

Comment: YES! Thank you @laalto! If you want to answer the question I will select your answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your app's `build.gradle` file for `resConfigs` directives that would filter out translations from the resulting APK. All your supported languages should be listed in `resConfigs`.

(Alternative: remove `resConfigs` altogether with the cost of getting possibly unused/unsupported resources for dependencies.)

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#unused-alt-resources